# What does "my vibe is" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english

Chicago PD.
There are 2 police officers in the scene, talking about a potential buy-bust, they are going to catch a gang dirty selling some sub-machine guns or Uzi in this case.

A black guy is going undercover. His dialogue:

> I'm fronting as a big dog of the 88th Street Vipers. **My vibe is** he likes selling to brothers because he feels like we're just going to wipe each other out, **help his cause anyway.** We got a get-to-know-you offer for five Uzis on the table. The meeting's in two hours, and I can't wait.

In this dialogue what does he mean by **my vibe is**?

In addition, I could not understand this phrase **help his cause anyway**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My vibe is**  means that his guess is, his intuition.
**help his cause anyway** has to be read in conjunction with the rest of the sentence. He is saying that, even if we don't wipe each other out, it will help his cause.
*Translation :*

> I guess that is he likes selling to brothers because he thinks that
> even if we don't wipe each other out, it will help his cause
> regardless.

Comment: What does he even mean by **cause**? This sentence is so confusing.

Comment: @Ghost That is not clear from the excerpt quoted, but a cause is something you believe in, an activity you do, or support. In this case one might think it was some criminal enterprise such as illegal arms dealing. He doesn't care if he sells weapons to the brothers just so long as his gun business flourishes.

Comment: Why does it feels like your definition of my vibe does not match the context? I am sorry. I could be wrong.

Comment: **My vibe** is slang and therefore subject to looser definitions than ordinary English. It comes from **vibrations** as in the Old Beach Boys song "I'm getting those good vibrations". Whilst the unreliable **Urban Dictionary** gives some definitions and examples that don't match my answer, it does say at one point it can mean "mood". In your example I think mood can be interpreted as feeling or guess.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it was an inaccurate use of slang.  [vibe](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vibe) means

> the mood or character of a place, situation, or piece of music

but he appears to be using it to mean what he has picked up about the character of this "big dog."  (Presuming that "as" really means "for."  Normally one does not "front as" a person.)

As for "help his cause anyway" it would appear he would be just as glad if blacks killed themselves out more quickly with the use of his drugs.  Presumably he wants them gone so whatever racial group the Vipers consist of can take over.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand your phrase **picked up** phrase. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: My reading is that the Vipers *are* Black, because the Black undercover cop is posing as one of their leaders (he is the "big dog", not the seller), and he is speculating that that is why the seller is happy to sell to him.